# AWS CDK Error: bucket policy already exists on bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am trying to create a lambda and a DynamoDB using CDK in java. When I try to do 'CDK Deploy' I face following error:

```
11:20:30 AM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::S3::BucketPolicy | StagingBucketPolicy
The bucket policy already exists on bucket xyz-cdk-toolkit-stagingbucket-1hpv60vcdqk7s.

CDK Version: 1.48.0
```

Comment: you already tried destroying the stack and doing a clean deploy ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This error occurs directly from CloudFormation, and as it says, the bucket you are adding the policy to, already has an **existing one**. CloudFormation **does not allow** for replacement/modification of bucket policies that were created outside of its control.

This is a security measure preventing you by accidentally changing existing policies.

If you want to control the bucket policy with CDK (or CloudFormation) you have to **recreate** it in CDK, delete the original one, and create using the CDK.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin for your response. Indeed this was the problem. This blog, [https://joebehrens.com/posts/cdk-bootstrap-existing-s3-bucket/] helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in comment above in response to @Marcin's reply, [this](https://joebehrens.com/posts/cdk-bootstrap-existing-s3-bucket/) blog helped me solve the problem. Following are the steps I followed:

1. Copied the cloud formation yaml snippet to a file named *s3-bucket.yml* provided in the blog.
2. Used aws cli command to first create this bucket:
   `aws cloudformation deploy --template-file resources/s3-bucket.yml --stack-name my-bucket-stack1`
3. Fired this CDK command to deploy my stack: `cdk deploy --toolkit-stack-name my-bucket-stack1`

These steps created my stack.